# C++AMP ARRAY_VIEW in matlab slow GPU

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab, visual-studio-2012, c++-amp

```
void Addx(float *z, float *x, float *y, size_t m, size_t n)
{
vector<float > vx(m*n); 
vector<float > vy(m*n);
vector<float > vz(m*n);

vx.assign(x, x + n*m);
vy.assign(y, y + n*m);
pick_accelerator();

extent<2> e(m, n);
array_view<const float, 2> xg(e, vx), yg(e, vy);
array_view<float, 2> zg(e, vz);
zg.discard_data();
parallel_for_each(e, [=](index<2> idx) restrict(amp)
{
zg[idx] = xg[idx] + yg[idx];
});

zg.synchronize();

for (int count = 0; count < m*n; count++)
{
    z[count] = vz[count];

}
}
```

My GPU is HD 7790, the program implemented in matlab mex. C++AMP.
I see the program is slow compared CPU Phenom II X6 (1055T) 2.8GHZ.

```
Size Array 1024x1024
GPU Elapsed time is 0.026684 seconds. 
CPU Elapsed time is 0.004970 seconds.
```

I see the program is slow compared CPU Phenom II X6 (1055T) 800MHZ(4 times slow).

```
Size Array 1024x1024
GPU Elapsed time is 0.064891 seconds.
CPU Elapsed time is 0.009650 seconds.
```

Relation Between CPU and GPU transfers Memory.
How I Accelerate the GPU program ?

```
CPU 130 Gflops AIDA64x FP (Phenom II X6 1055T)
GPU 1820 Gflops AIDA64x FP (HD 7790 OC)
```

Comment: **How to access Address Memory GPU Radeon in MATLAB**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are doing enough compute on the GPU to offset the additional cost of copying the data. You are copying 4Mb of data per array and only doing 1024 * 1024 addition operations on the GPU. There also no opportunities for making use of tile static memory (which is much faster than global memory) for such a simple algorithm. So in several ways this is pretty much a worst case scenario for any GPU solution.

This probably isn't ever going to be faster than doing it on the CPU due to the additional copy time. I'm assuming that this is just a 'hello world' test program and you are actually going to implement something more complex. In which case you should see better results.

Note: You are using `discard_data()` and `array_view<const float, 2>` correctly so you've already minimized the number of copies required.

Make sure you are testing release builds with the appropriate compiler optimization flags to get the best timings.

***MEX***

With respect to MEX (which I've never used) I'm not sure it has any special features that allow you to access GPU memory or resources other than through an API like C++AMP or CUDA. The following paper might be useful, [Accelerating MATLAB Code 
Using GPUs](http://www.smast.umassd.edu/CMLAB/notebook/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/cuda_matlab.pdf). If your application uses another framework which also runs on the GPU it is possible to map to and from DirectX buffers and C++AMP `array` instances. This is covered in [Interoperability between Direct 3D and C++ AMP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/12/29/interoperability-between-direct-3d-and-c-amp.aspx?Redirected=true) and in chapter 11 of the [C++ AMP Book](http://ampbook.codeplex.com/).

Comment: **thanks**. How to access Address Memory GPU C++AMP in MATLAB with mex?

Comment: So are you asking a different question? Is so probably best to post it separately. I thing this one just covers general copy performance issues from CPU to GPU. I added a link to my answer for the MEX part.